# IF statement does not work inside Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to show a row only if I have data for it. The code which i have is:

```
<p:dataTable id="comments" var="comment"
        value="#{agencyBean.getCommentByAgency(agencyBean.tAgency)}"
        paginator="true" >

        <p:column>  
            #{comment.author.name}  
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <c:if test="${not empty comment.positiveComment}">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="positive.png" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>  #{comment.positiveComment}  </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <br />
            </c:if>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

But nevertheless I have data, the row is not shown. How can i implement this logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to place the condition expression in the `<p:row>`'s tag itself, by using its `rendered` attribute :

```
<p:column>
    <p:row rendered="#{not empty comment.positiveComment}">
        <p:column>
            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="positive.png" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>  #{comment.positiveComment}  </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <br />
</p:column>
```

Comment: You mean *try using `rendered` attribute instead*.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm meaning.

Comment: @Tot by the way, the explanation about why `<c:if>` didn't work is here: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/1065197)